# How to replace a character in a variable in tcsh script while using inside a makefile function

Tags: shell, makefile, tcsh

I have a makefile with the below content :

```
mytarget:
    @$(call my_func, echo \"hello world\")

define my_func
    $(eval var := $(1))

    if [[ "$(var)" != "" ]]; then \
        $(var); \
    fi;
endef
```

while executing with make command , this prints  "hello world"   (enclosed with the double quotes)
All I want is to get rid of the " from the echo "hello world" before the conditional if check.

I tried with below statement but of no use :

var2 = $(echo $var | tr '"' ''
then use $(var2) in the if condition instead of $(var)
It is not working.
Any help will be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: There is no `tcsh` script here.  I assume that the missing end-paren in your target `$(shell ...)` invocation is a cut and paste error.

Comment: I suspect this is an XY problem.  Using `eval` to set make variables in a recipe is almost always a bad idea and leads to many problems.

Comment: I have corrected the missing end-paren. If I do echo $SHELL it gives tcsh. What is the solution you suggest here instead of eval and how do I get rid of the " in the output?

Comment: Doing `echo $SHELL` in your shell has no relationship to what shell make will use when it runs commands.  make will _always_ use `/bin/sh` as the shell to run commands, unless you explicitly override the make `SHELL` variable (not the shell's `SHELL` variable).  It would be an absolute portability nightmare if every shell script ran whatever personal shell the person starting `make` happened to be using.

Comment: ok , right. Thanks . what about getting rid of the " in the output ? how can I replace it before the if condition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should never add `@` to your makefile recipes until they are working 100%.  Otherwise you're trying to debug your makefiles blindfolded.

Your entire makefile script seems like it could just be written as:

```
mytarget:
        $(call my_func, echo "hello world")

my_func = $1
```

and it would work exactly the same way: if `my_func` is called with an empty argument then `$1` expands to the empty string, which is what you're trying to test anyway.  Presumably you have some reason for wanting a more complicated configuration but, as I mentioned in my comment, it seems like an XY problem.

I'll give you a short answer: make doesn't care about quoting or about backslashes.  Any quotes or backslashes you use are passed verbatim to the shell.  So if you pass `echo \"foo\"` to the shell, it will print the quotes.  That's exactly as expected.

If you remove the `@`, as I mention above, things will be a lot more clear to you.

So, why are you adding backslashes?  It appears you're adding them because otherwise the condition `if [ "$1" != "" ]` will expand to `if [ "echo "hello world"" != "" ]` which is a syntax error.

One simple solution is to use single quotes instead of double quotes:

```
mytarget:
        $(call my_func, echo "hello world")

define my_func
    if [ '$1' != '' ]; then \
        $1; \
    fi;
endef
```

Of course, this will fail if you call `my_func` with a value containing singe-quotes.

You have two solutions:

First is to use a *make* conditional, not a shell conditional, since make doesn't care about quotes etc.  That gives you:

```
mytarget:
        $(call my_func, echo "hello world")

my_func = $(if $1,$1)
```

but that's the same as my first suggestion, just using `$1` by itself.

If you really, really have to do this in the shell then you have to quote things for the shell.  Make's `subst` function can do that for you:

```
mytarget:
        $(call my_func, echo "hello world")

define my_func
    if [ '$(subst ','\'',$1)' != '' ]; then \
        $1; \
    fi;
endef
```

which replaces all instances of `'` with `'\''`.